# How to extract month from original date?

Tags: r

I have a sample data below:

```
  original_date    first_payment_date LTV DTI FICO
       01/2007            03/2007     56  37  734
       01/2007            04/2007     80  11  762
       01/2006            02/2007     80  28  656
```

I want to extract the month part from the original_date, but when I use the `months` function it throws an error because it is looking for a value like '01/01/2007'. Is it possible to get the month part without converting the value to '01/01/2007'?

Comment: What do you mean by cut?  Do you just want another column with the name of the month?  Or do you want to create multiple data frames with only one value of `original_date` in each...?

Comment: @datapaRty, I don't list all of the data, but there are many 01/2007 rows, thus I need to cut them in to a '01/2007' group

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first two characters in original_date is your month.This should return you the month part only.

```
select LEFT(original_date,2) as original_date_month 
 from yourtable
```

Comment: this is sql, and I need a sequence like 01/2010, intead of month

Comment: Is it possible to provide a sample result of what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `separate` function from `tidyr` to separate your dates into month and year columns. Then you can use `mutate_each` to get the abbreviations of the monts instead of the numbers. Use either `month.abb` to get the abbreviations or `month.name` to get the full name.

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
df %>% 
  separate(original_date, c("original_month", "original_year"), sep = "/", convert = TRUE) %>%
  separate(first_payment_date, c("first_payment_month", "first_payment_year"), sep = "/", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(month.abb[.]), contains("_month"))
## original_month original_year first_payment_month first_payment_year LTV DTI FICO
## 1            Jan          2007                 Mar               2007  56  37  734
## 2            Jan          2007                 Apr               2007  80  11  762
## 3            Jan          2006                 Feb               2007  80  28  656
```

The data I used:

```
df <- data.frame(original_date = c("01/2007", "01/2007", "01/2006"), 
                 first_payment_date = c("03/2007", "04/2007", "02/2007"), 
                 LTV = c(56L, 80L, 80L), 
                 DTI = c(37L, 11L, 28L), 
                 FICO = c(734L, 762L, 656L), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```